# Question about OAuth/XAuth Authentication

Tags: iphone, authentication, oauth, xauth

When I develop a App Project on iPhone, it's need to authenticate.

My basic requirement is to have custom login screen. But the Service providers currently provide OAuth protocal only, not XAuth protocal. Does this mean that if I use OAuth protocol, it will can not be achieved what I need (custom login screen), and I must be loaded the service provider's interface by UIWebView to enter user name and password?

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

For OAuth v1, yes that is the only option.
For [OAuth v2](http://wiki.oauth.net/OAuth-2) there are more "flows" which can be used.  See this [article](http://hueniverse.com/2010/05/introducing-oauth-2-0/) for a intro to OAuth v2.

So it all depends on who you are connecting to as to what version of OAuth they support.  You may like to connect whoever you are connecting to to see if they provide other options.  I know people that are working with a vendor so that the vendor are supporting some of the OAuth v2 extendations for them to make it nicer for there mobile applications as the "web" view looks shit on mobile devices.

On the other side, once you have the token it's yours until revoked.  This means you can save it and use it from then onwards.  This means you may only have to display the login only when the token fails.